# 2005 BMW r1150r leaking gas

Tags: motorcycle, bmw, fuel-leak

I have a 2005 BMW r1150r and I am getting a constant drip of gas coming from both vent tubes that run down near the right foot peg. I have removed the tank and replaced the fuel pump inside and also removed the charcoal filter and disconnected the regulator. If I plug both tube, the gas leaks out of the top of tank. Seems like there is some kind of vacuum effect going on.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Is it leaking when running, sitting, or both? Also, can you possibly provide images of the area where it is leaking? This will be of vast benefit to anyone who wants to chime in. :)